# Class cannot be downcast to immediate subclass with same fields

Tags: java, clone

I'm making a package that contains several playing card classes, the difference between them being that they have different freedoms regarding their natural orderings. `DefaultCard` has the "default ordering" (ace-high, 2 < 3 < 4 < ... < A, CLUBS < DIAMONDS < HEARTS < SPADES, ranks are compared before suits), and this ordering cannot be changed. `ConstantOrderingCard` allows the ordering to be set through constructors, but it cannot be changed after instantiation. `VariableOrderingCard` allows the ordering to be set during instantiation and after.

The class hierarchy looks like this:

```
              [AbstractCard]             [Joker]
             /            \
         [DefaultCard]   [ConstantOrderingCard]
                             \
                         [VariableOrderingCard]
```

In order to allow copies of decks to be made more easily, I had all of these classes implement `Cloneable` and overrode their `clone` methods. `AbstractCard`, `DefaultCard`, and `Joker` have no mutable, reference-type fields, so I overrode them in the same, very simple manner. This is what I did (I'm using AbstractCard as an example):

```
@Override
protected AbstractCard clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
    return (AbstractCard)super.clone();
}
```

Since `ConstantOrderingCard` does have mutable, reference-type fields, I returned an explicit copy. `VariableOrderingCard` has no fields not inherited from `ConstantOrderingCard`; all it contains are setters. So, I figured I could call `ConstantOrderingCard.clone` and downcast it, like I did above. The `clone` methods for every class but `VariableOrderingCard` compiled without error and worked perfectly at runtime, but `VariableOrderingCard` gave me a `ClassCastException`, saying I could not cast `ConstantOrderingCard` to `VariableOrderingCard`. I have no idea why this would be, considering it defines no fields of its own, and especially since it worked for all of the others. Any insight about this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the `clone` method for `ConstantOrderingCard`:

```
@Override
protected ConstantOrderingCard clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
    if (rankOrdering != DEFAULT_RANK_ORDERING &&
        suitOrdering != DEFAULT_SUIT_ORDERING)
    {
        int[] rankOrderingCopy = rankOrdering.values().stream().mapToInt(
            Integer::intValue).toArray();
        int[] suitOrderingCopy = suitOrdering.values().stream().mapToInt(
            Integer::intValue).toArray();
        return new ConstantOrderingCard(RANK, SUIT, rankOrderingCopy,
            suitOrderingCopy, compareSuitsFirst);
    }
    else if (rankOrdering != DEFAULT_RANK_ORDERING)
    {
        int[] rankOrderingCopy = rankOrdering.values().stream().mapToInt(
            Integer::intValue).toArray();
        return new ConstantOrderingCard(RANK, SUIT, rankOrderingCopy,
            compareSuitsFirst);
    }
    else if (suitOrdering != DEFAULT_SUIT_ORDERING)
    {
        int[] suitOrderingCopy = suitOrdering.values().stream().mapToInt(
            Integer::intValue).toArray();
        return new ConstantOrderingCard(RANK, SUIT, suitOrderingCopy,
            compareSuitsFirst);
    }
    else
    {
        return new ConstantOrderingCard(RANK, SUIT, compareSuitsFirst);
    }
}
```

and here is the `clone` method for `VariableOrderingCard`:

```
@Override
protected VariableOrderingCard clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
    return (VariableOrderingCard)super.clone();
}
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you show us the clone() method of VariableOrderingCard  that fails.

Comment: There, I apologize. Like I said, it's the same as what I did in the example for `AbstractCard`.

Comment: `super.clone()` returns a `ConstantOrderingCard` created with `new ConstantOrderingCard(...)` so at runtime it is *not* a `VariableOrderingCard`, you can't cast it, the error is normal. Perhaps there is a way to do what you want, using a generic cloning method, with a bit more work... (sorry don't know how off the top of my head)

Comment: Good point. Somehow I got it into my head that you could downcast anyway if the subclass didn't have any non-inherited fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.clone always creates an instance of the same class as the object being cloned, but your implementation of clone() in ConstantOrderingCard is not using Object.clone, so there is no Java-system-level “magic” happening.  `new ConstantOrderingCard` always creates an instance of ConstantOrderingCard, and nothing else.

An alternative approach is to continue to use Object.clone, then have your custom `clone` method account for the fields that need to be deeply copied:

```
@Override
protected ConstantOrderingCard clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
    ConstantOrderingCard copy = (ConstantOrderingCard) super.clone();

    copy.rankOrdering = new HashMap<>(copy.rankOrdering);
    copy.suitOrdering = new HashMap<>(copy.suitOrdering);

    return copy;
}
```

(You haven’t shown the rest of your ConstantOrderingCard class, so I’m not sure that’s sufficient, but you get the idea.)

Comment: That worked. I'm fairly new to Java and static typing in general (I've previously only worked in Python), so I'm still getting the hang of things.

Comment: And if your fields are final, there's my approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the inheritance  hierarchy, VariableOrderingCard IS A ConstantOrderingCard  but that does not mean ConstantOrderingCard is a VariableOrderingCard.

When you call ConstantOrderingCard.clone(), you create an object of type ConstantOrderingCard. Downcasting is possible when you have an object of a sub-type that has a reference of the super type. Unfortunately, in this case you have an object of the super type.

Let's say you create a String and store it as an object reference:

```
//will compile
Object o = new String("hello world");
String s = (String) o;
```

However, a VariableOrderingCard reference cannot be used for anything other than a VariableOrderingCard object.

```
//will also compile
ConstantOrderingCard c = new VariableOrderingCard(...);
VariableOrderingCard v = (VariableOrderingCard) c;
```

However, calling super.clone() creates an object of type ConstantOrderingCard, equivalent to:

```
//not gonna compile 
VariableOrderingCard v = (VariableOrderingCard) new ConstantOrderingCard(...);
```

A full article on this topic:
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/downcasting-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

`super.clone()` returns a `ConstantOrderingCard` created with `new ConstantOrderingCard(...)` so at runtime it is not a `VariableOrderingCard`, you can't cast it, the error is normal.

With Java 8 you could do something like this to dynamically create objects of the type you need (I reproduced a similar hierarchy, only kept the essential bits, with dummy fields for the important class, you'll get the idea and adapt to your own code):

```
abstract class AbstractCard {}

interface ConstantOrderingCardSupplier {
    ConstantOrderingCard get(String a, int b);
}

class ConstantOrderingCard extends AbstractCard {
    String a;
    int b;
    ConstantOrderingCard(String a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    protected ConstantOrderingCard clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        /* Here you implement your logic,
         * and when you need to create an instance,
         * instead of using the constructor, you do this: */
        return supplier().get(this.a, this.b);
    }

    ConstantOrderingCardSupplier supplier() {
        return ConstantOrderingCard::new;
    }
}

class VariableOrderingCard extends ConstantOrderingCard {

    VariableOrderingCard(String a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    protected VariableOrderingCard clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (VariableOrderingCard) super.clone();
    }

    ConstantOrderingCardSupplier supplier() {
        return VariableOrderingCard::new;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good solution, but I'm almost certain I won't need any more card classes (it's my understanding, based on my fairly limited knowledge of Java, that interfaces are primarily intended for use by multiple classes), so I wanted to keep things fairly simple, considering `ConstantOrderingCard` has only one subclass. If I ever decide to define more, though, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Yes sure, the accepted answer is much simpler! I did not think of it because I'm too used to have final fields, so I added constraints of my own that you do not have.